# Dynamically add item to jQuery Select2 control that uses AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a jQuery Select2 control that uses AJAX to populate:

```
<input type="text" name="select2" id="select2" style='width:400px' value="999">

var initialSelection = { id: '999', text:"Some initial option"};

$("#select2").select2({
    placeholder: "Select Option",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: { 
        url: "/servletToGetMyData",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) { return { term: term }; },
        results: function (data, page) {  return { results: data.results} }
    },
    initSelection : function(element, callback){ callback(initialSelection); },     
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
});
```

The AJAX links to a database of possible options and as you can see requires two characters of input.

The problem is the user can use a dialog to add a new option if the option doesn't exist in the database.  Upon return from that dialog, I try:

```
var o = $("<option/>", {value: newID, text: newText});
$('#select2').append(o);
$('#select2 option[value="' + newID + '"]').prop('selected',true);
$('#select2').trigger('change');
```

But it doesn't work.  The same exact code works for non-AJAX Select2 boxes.  I've tried various alternatives, like using `$('#select2').select2("val", newID);` but it doesn't work.

I've even tried completely deleting the Select2 control.  However, `$('#select2').remove()` only removes the original <input> field but leaves the Select2 control lingering around.  Note that the page has more than one Select2 control, so I can't use a class selector for Select2 controls as it will remove other controls that I need.

Any idea how to either a) dynamically add an option to a Select2 control that uses AJAX; or b) completely delete a Select2 control so that it can be programmatically added back? Or any other solution...

**Edit**
I found another question that shows how to remove a select2 element, using .select2("destroy").  This works but is, in my opinion, sub-optimal.  I would much prefer to be able to just add the option than to destroy and re-create the select2.

Comment: Is it bad to mention the version of plugin?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This provided a simple solution: 
[Set data in Select2 after insert with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311657/set-data-in-select2-after-insert-with-ajax)

```
$("#select2").select2('data', {id: newID, text: newText});
```

Comment: this solution do not work for the select multiple, just add selected items, but not in the options list.

Comment: it is not working in multiple select dropdown, it is neither appearing as seleted nor it is appearing in option list.

Comment: This works for older versions of Select2.  For version 4, see the answer by alexw.

Answer (score 58):

This is a lot easier to do starting in select2 v4.  You can create a `new Option`, and append it to the `select` element directly.  See my [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/zremOV) or the example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#state").select2({
      tags: true
    });
      
    $("#btn-add-state").on("click", function(){
      var newStateVal = $("#new-state").val();
      // Set the value, creating a new option if necessary
      if ($("#state").find("option[value=" + newStateVal + "]").length) {
        $("#state").val(newStateVal).trigger("change");
      } else { 
        // Create the DOM option that is pre-selected by default
        var newState = new Option(newStateVal, newStateVal, true, true);
        // Append it to the select
        $("#state").append(newState).trigger('change');
      } 
    });  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="state" class="js-example-basic-single" type="text" style="width:90%">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input id="new-state" type="text" />
<button type="button" id="btn-add-state">Set state value</button>
```

Hint: try entering existing values into the text box, like "AL" or "WY".  Then try adding some new values.

Comment: it works but problem is when I change option, newly added option gone

Comment: This is the way to go. TLDR: `$("#my_select").append(new Option("Label", "value", true, true));`

Comment: @alexw append This method work perfectly fine for single selectbox, but not for multiselect. Can you please suggest.

Comment: İt works but how do we add additional data into select option ?

Comment: @alexw. Is it possible to pass extra HTML code in this way ?

Comment: This does not work for me... select2 rejects if I try to use a <select> tag with ajax. I have to use <input> tag, and attaching <option> to <input> does not work.

Answer (score 29):

In case of Select2 Version 4+

it has changed syntax and you need to write like this:

```
// clear all option
$('#select_with_blank_data').html('').select2({data: [{id: '', text: ''}]});

// clear and add new option
$("#select_with_data").html('').select2({data: [
 {id: '', text: ''},
 {id: '1', text: 'Facebook'},
 {id: '2', text: 'Youtube'},
 {id: '3', text: 'Instagram'},
 {id: '4', text: 'Pinterest'}]});



//  append option
$("#select_with_data").append('<option value="5">Twitter</option>');
$("#select_with_data").val('5');
$("#select_with_data").trigger('change');
```

Comment: This is "documented" as no longer possible in select2 code. You'll get a warning if you set 'debug:true' in the select2 constructor:
"Select2: Data can no longer be set using `select2("data")`. You should consider setting the value instead using `$element.val()`."

Answer (score 23):

In Select2 4.0.2

```
$("#yourId").append("<option value='"+item+"' selected>"+item+"</option>");
$('#yourId').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish I had more time to develop an alternative to select2.... I can't believe that this worked for multiple options and what I have to do for single options is totally different...thanks @Digvijay

Comment: fyi, still working in 4.0.6 tested and needed today... THX

Answer (score 10):

I have resolved  issue with the help of this link  http://www.bootply.com/122726. hopefully will help you

Add option in select2 jquery and bind your ajax call with created link id(#addNew) for new option from backend. 
and the code

```
 $.getScript('http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-3.4.5/select2.js',function(){

  $("#mySel").select2({
    width:'240px',
    allowClear:true,
    formatNoMatches: function(term) {
        /* customize the no matches output */
        return "<input class='form-control' id='newTerm' value='"+term+"'><a href='#' id='addNew' class='btn btn-default'>Create</a>"
    }
  })
  .parent().find('.select2-with-searchbox').on('click','#addNew',function(){
    /* add the new term */
    var newTerm = $('#newTerm').val();
    //alert('adding:'+newTerm);
    $('<option>'+newTerm+'</option>').appendTo('#mySel');
    $('#mySel').select2('val',newTerm); // select the new term
    $("#mySel").select2('close');       // close the dropdown
  })

});



<div class="container">
    <h3>Select2 - Add new term when no search matches</h3>
    <select id="mySel">
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
        <option>Four</option>
        <option>Five</option>
        <option>Six</option>
        <option>Twenty Four</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share at least a summary of what you found behind the link. This in case the link stops working in the future.

Comment: select2 javascript modification and going to update the answer

Comment: any chance to upgrade the current code for select 2 version 4.0. Current sample code is break. Thanks

Comment: @Suneel The solution provided you is creating issue , after adding in dropdown  http://prntscr.com/a1r0b1

Answer (score 9):

Extending on Bumptious Q Bangwhistle's answer:

```
$('#select2').append($('<option>', { 
    value: item,
    text : item 
})).select2();
```

This would add the new options into the `<select>` tags and lets select2 re-render it.

Answer (score 5):

I did it this way and it worked for me like a charm.

```
var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, 

    text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

    $(".js-example-data-array").select2({
      data: data
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#my_select").select2('destroy').empty().select2({data: [{id: 1, text: "new_item"}]});
```

Comment: Please provide some more information to your answer. An explanation could help.

Answer (score 2):

To get dynamic tagging to work with ajax, here's what I did.

**Select2 version 3.5**

This is easy in version 3.5 because it offers the `createSearchChoice` hook. It even works for multiple select, as long as `multiple: true` and `tags: true` are set.

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="locations" value="Whistler, BC" />
```

JS

```
$('input[name="locations"]').select2({
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
    if (!data.length)
      return { id: term, text: term };
    },
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/v1.1/locations',
    dataType: 'json'
  }
});
```

The idea here is to use select2's `createSearchChoice` hook which passes you both the `term` that the user entered and the ajax response (as `data`). If ajax returns an empty list, then tell select2 to offer the user-entered `term` as an option.

Demo: https://johnny.netlify.com/select2-examples/version3

**Select2 version 4.X**

Version 4.X doesn't have a `createSearchChoice` hook anymore, but here's how I did the same thing.

HTML

```
  <select name="locations" multiple>
    <option value="Whistler, BC" selected>Whistler, BC</option>
  </select>
```

JS

```
$('select[name="locations"]').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/v1.1/locations',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function(params) {
      this.data('term', params.term);
      return params;
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      if (data.length)
        return {
          results: data
        };
      else
        return {
          results: [{ id: this.$element.data('term'), text: this.$element.data('term') }]
        };
    }
  }
});
```

The ideas is to stash the term that the user typed into jQuery's data store inside select2's `data` hook. Then in select2's `processResults` hook, I check if the ajax response is empty. If it is, I grab the stashed term that the user typed and return it as an option to select2.

Demo: https://johnny.netlify.com/select2-examples/version4