# How to set value programmatically on 4.0.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

The Method from docs works well only for static select. I'm talking about the code

```
$('#my-select').val(id).trigger('change');
```

But this code doesn't work properly when I have no static options. All the data I get from ajax response. I'm trying to add default option into the DOM, select by `.val(id)` and trigger it by `.trigger('change')` but label of select2 span is empty. It changes if I reinit select2 for this select, but then widget lose ajax support.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVpYvB)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add item to jQuery Select2 control that uses AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428361/dynamically-add-item-to-jquery-select2-control-that-uses-ajax)

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428361/dynamically-add-item-to-jquery-select2-control-that-uses-ajax/35386009#35386009, and my codepen: http://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/zremOV

Comment: Check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVpYvB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the option and place the label. Here is a creepy work solution:

```
var $select2 = $('#select2');
var newState = new Option(val_text, val_id, true, true);
$select2.empty().append(newState).trigger('change');
$('#select2-'+$select2.attr('id')+'-container').text(val_text);
```