# select2 add option with ajax enabled

Tags: jquery-select2

I have this select2:

```
 $('#order_address_select').select2({
            placeholder: "Sratr typing...",
            ajax: {
                url: 'mysite/myurl',
                dataType: 'json',
            },
            tags: true,
        });
```

And then I am trying to add options dynamically

```
var newOption = new Option('myoption',1,false,false);
    $('#order_address_select').append(newOption).trigger('change');
    $('#order_address_select').select2('open');
```

new option appends in my `<select></select>` tag, but nothing appears in dropdown list. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428361/dynamically-add-item-to-jquery-select2-control-that-uses-ajax)

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui yes, i tried this, still nothing appears in dropdown list