# Ajax selecting multiple values in select2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

i am working with select 2, and i have data coming from ajax in json format.

**View:**

```
<select class="form-control qual_id" multiple>
    <option value="">-Select Degree-</option>
    <option value="1">SSC</option>
    <option value="2">HSC</option>
    <option value="3">BBA</option>
    <option value="4">MBA</option>
</select>
```

**Ajax:**

```
var defaultValue = 1,2 // (it can be one id or two ids)

$(`.qual_id option[value=${defaultValue}]`).attr('selected', true);
```

**select2:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.qual_id').select2({
  width: 'resolve',
  maximumSelectionLength: 2
});
</script>
```

> if i remove multiple from select tag and and do it without select2 with one id, it is
>   working fine, but how can i do it by selecting multiple values in select.

**Console:**

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .qual_id
>   option[value=1,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question few months ago. You can refer to it from [Dynamically add item to jQuery Select2 control that uses AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38084685/5326191).

To answer your question, consider this example.

```
for(let i=0; i<jsonResponse.length; i++) {
    $(".qual_id").each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == jsonResponse[i]) {
            // select the option
        }
    });
}
$('.qual_id').trigger('change');
```

What you are looking for is **.trigger()** method. Refer [Select2 Docs](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event)

Comment: i tried var defaultValue = data.qualifs

for(let i=0; i<defaultValue.length; i++) {
    $(".qual_id").each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == defaultValue[i]) {
            $(`.qual_id option[value=${defaultValue}]`).attr('selected', true);
        }
    });
}
$('.qual_id').trigger('change');

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for it & share the link.

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/1cszw2yg/1/ will fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, how to set selected values on top of  list?

Comment: To answer your 'Force the selected values to top', closest solution I could find is https://jsbin.com/cizehajema/2/edit?html,js,output. Also, please up-vote my 2nd comment (with jsfiddle link) for future learners to easily identity the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: i read about .prepend in jquery which shows selected on top, how to use prepend in my case?

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaultValue = [1,2];
$(`.qual_id`).val(defaultValue);
```

This should set values 1 and 2 to be selected by default.

Comment: console:Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .qual_id option[value=1,2]

Comment: Wait, do you want to pre-select 2 values with select2?

Comment: if default value is set to 1 or 2, or both when page loads that value should be pre selected.

Comment: I've edited my comment, missunderstood what you wanted initially, hope new edit helps!

Comment: how to set them as selected? and everything else non selected?